# Non-blocking calls in PHP with GuzzleHttp REST API client

Tags: php, api, rest, guzzle

I would like to make a non-blocking REST API call using PHP library GuzzleHttp.

1. I have a REST API server (`http://api.example.com/v1/wait`)
2. `wait` method does not do anything, except `sleep(10)`.
3. I am running the following from PHP CLI with `future` param:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->get('http://api.example.com/v1/wait', [
    'future' => true,
    'body' => [
        'some' => 'var'
    ],
]);
echo 'OK';
```

I am expecting that "OK" would echo immediately, without waiting for completion of REST API call. Instead, the execution is suspended for 10 seconds - that is the `sleep()` duration in REST `wait()` method.

According to Guzzle documentation:

> You can send asynchronous requests by setting the future request option to true

I am not interesting in call completion callbacks, all I want is to give API some (possibly, slow) task to work on and get on with life.

I have also tried cURL's own multirequest, several other libraries - the result is the same. Execution is blocked, waiting for response to arrive from API server.

So, what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even using `cURL` native "multithreading" the maximum execution time will be the *time required for the longest query to finish*, so *PHP will wait for the latest query* anyway. The non-blocking term here is in the terms of current script (*for e.g. 5 non-blocking request at once, but they are all will be finished in terms of this script*). In other words, script will not leave them unless all requests report at least smth.

Possible solution is [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to *init some separate thread* to accomplish your task *without waiting for it* to finish. There are, so called *zombie processes* as the result of uncontrolled forks, but you can give it a try in your case, bec. it is not forever-running process (*aka worker*).

Here is [one of the many](http://oliversmith.io/technology/2011/10/07/speeding-up-php-using-process-forking-for-image-resizing/) articles on `pcntl_fork` approach.

Comment: yeah, it looks like that. there's no way to achieve it other than using pcntl_fork.

I found this in Guzzle's destructor:

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // Finish any open connections before terminating the script.
        if ($this->handles) {
            $this->execute();
        }
}